# Selecting the first div with class

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Basically I have a row of links and a div sitting below them which content gets loaded into.

There are several blocks of these repeated throughout the page so I only want to select the first div with the class "active" which is below the current link.

Here's a fiddle below which shows the problem in action. As you can see I tried to use `:first` but this selects the first one in the page and not the first one below the current link.

http://jsfiddle.net/wdcn6/11/

```
$(function () {
$('.accordionContent').hide();

    $(".accordionButton").click(function () {

        var content_id = $(this).attr('href');

        $('.active:first').html($(content_id).html()).show(500);
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$('.active:first')` by itself will always match the very first `.active` in the document.

To start the `:first` match only after the link that was clicked, you can either use [`$(this).find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find) with a sibling combinator:

```
$(this).find('~ .active:first').html($(content_id).html()).show(500);
```

[jsFiddle preview](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/wdcn6/12)

Or use [`$(this).nextAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll):

```
$(this).nextAll('.active:first').html($(content_id).html()).show(500);
```

[jsFiddle preview](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/wdcn6/13)

Answer (score 0):

Check this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/wdcn6/14/

```
$(function () {
    $('.accordionContent').hide();

        $(".accordionButton").click(function () {

            var content_id = $(this).attr('href');

           $(this).nextAll('.active').first().html($(content_id).html()).show(500);
            return false;
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this:

```
$(content_id + ' ~ .active:first').html($(content_id).html()).show(500);
```